# Changing the color between NavigationBar and first cell

Tags: ios, swift

How can I change the color between NavigationBar and first cell(Space that appears When I scroll down)?
I am creating app with custom tableView with View on top. 
I have tried "self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green" which did not solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: What code have attempted?

Comment: This is the background color of the tableView. You can change it and it will change.

Comment: try using cell.backgroundcolor = white , but tableview.backgroundcolor change to whatever u want ( this wil help u differntiate b/w nav and first cell)

Comment: Sorry explanation was not enough. I want to change the color of space that appears When I scroll down.

Comment: @risa8 this looks very similar to having `translucent` property set to true on the navigation bar, can you see if it's disabled?

Comment: I have checked and translucent Naviation Bar is set.

Comment: @risa8 try disabling it and see how your table view constraints behave in interface builder

Comment: I have tried but there was no change:/

Comment: I doubt it but it really might be a blank tableHeaderView, I still kind of think it might be related to having a non-opaque navigation bar. Try the "debug view hierarchy" and see if that white slice at the top is part of the table view or an unrelated view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all you need to do is change the background colour of your TableView.

In Code:

```
// OBJ-C
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
//SWIFT
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor
```

Or in Interface Builder:

[image]

Hope that helps

Explanation:
[image]

Comment: umm I actually do not want to change the back ground color of tableView. It is the Space that appears When I scroll down.

Comment: Well the space that appears is the Background Colour of the table view.
If you want to have a different background in the Cells, I would suggest to play around with the Cells BG colours in combination with the TableView BG colour

Comment: But the background of the tableview is what you see when you scroll down. So you do want to change this

Comment: See the new annotated screenshot @risa8